# OpenCV - Is it possible to separate contours per grayscale value in Image?

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am fairly new to OpenCV and am currently learning how to extract digits from images using contours. The image I am referring to can be found here:

[image]

The problem I'm running into is that the grayscale values of the numbers and lines/dots can be quite similar and as a result, their contours are merged. How would I resolve this?

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
img = cv2.imread(filename=('data/6737,K.png'))
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgray,255,
                cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C,cv2.THRESH_BINARY,11,2)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
                cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

If OpenCV has an option that allows separating contours per grayscale value, it might be possible to extract individual digits. Or maybe there's another solution to this that I haven't tried?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by setting pixels from columns with a low summed grayscale value to the background color (i.e. cutting the horizontal line). Thanks!